# How to query for Test Step count in VSTS Test Cases?

Tags: azure-devops

Our team is in the process of migrating to VSTS and is creating new Test cases as well as recreating Test Cases from old Word documents. Some Test Cases were created as placeholders to be backfilled with Test Steps at a later time.

Is it possible to retrieve the count of steps in a test case?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Comment: Sorry, it took few days to get back to the code. It works great, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the count of test case steps through API:

```
var u = new Uri("https://XXX.visualstudio.com");
            var c = new VssClientCredentials();
            TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, c);
            _tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

            ITestManagementService test_service = (ITestManagementService)_tfs.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
            ITestManagementTeamProject project = test_service.GetTeamProject("[team project]");

            ITestPlan plan = project.TestPlans.Find([test plan id]);

            ITestCase testcase = project.TestCases.Find([test case id]);

            Console.WriteLine(testcase.Actions.Count);
            Console.Read();
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what NuGet packages will be needed for this code to work. I Installed "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client", "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client" and "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient" but it did not work.

Comment: I got it, I was missing "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient"

Comment: Is there a way I can get the Status of the action(Pass/Fail)?